# Using compiler directives and macros in verilog, how to use multiple macros conditionally in verilog?

Tags: verilog, hdl, compiler

I have 2 macros in verilog used them as below.

> ```
>    `define TB_4
>    `define TB_8
>    `ifdef TB_4
>        `define tab_4
>        `define tab_8
>    `else
>        `ifdef TB_8
>            `define tab_1
>            `define tab_2
>        `else
>            `define tab_3
>        `endif
>    `endif
> ```

Can I define macros like this? or is there any alternative like logical OR in`ifdef operation.

Answer (score 0):

There are no operations permitted in `` `ifdef ``, but the code you wrote is fine.

You can get the effect of OR or AND operations by additional defines.

```
 `ifdef TB_4
       `define TB_4_OR_8
       `ifdef TB_8
          `define TB_4_AND_8
       `endif
 `else
     `ifdef TB_8
           `define TB_4_OR_8
     `endif
 `endif
```

Comment: Or can we use `ifdef TB_4 || TB_8 inside module?

Comment: No operations permitted

Comment: or anythings as `if DEFINE TB_8 || TB_4

Comment: NO OPERATIONS PERMITTED